# google places api more than 60 results

Tags: google-places-api

I'm using places text search api to locate the stores of a brand in a city. But there are more than 60 stores for those brands in a city. But through google places api I'm getting only 60 results, which I can get using pagination method(page_token) .
**Is it possible to access more than 60 results using google places api.**

API::
First request :https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=pizza+hut+in+bangalore&sensor=true&key=

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to get more than 60 results in Places API. Some people tried to file a feature request in Google issue tracker, but Google rejected it with the following comment

**Unfortunately Places API is not in a position to return more than 60 results.
Besides technical reasons (latency, among others) returning more than 60 results would make the API be more like a database or general-purpose search engine. We'd rather improve search quality so that users don't need to go so far down a long list of results.**

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35826799

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to access more than 60 results. If you think this would be a useful feature, please submit a [Places API - Feature Request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request).

Comment: An request has been raised. Please vote for this if anybody is facing the same problem.

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4422&q=places%20api%2060&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal

Comment: @hey Chris Green have you got the solutions for more that 60 results.