# How can I get more than 60 results from the Google Places API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I was able to obtain the post office result by the Google Places API call below.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=35.610418,139.182358&radius=1000000&types=post_office&language=ja&sensor=false&key="MyKey"

But, The third page does not have "next_page_token" tags, you can not retrieve the results following.

How can I get the more than 60 results after the fourth pages?.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382669/google-places-api-more-than-60-results)

Comment: You can reduce the radius to 4-5 km and get 60 results and then move your center 10km east/west/north/south and search again

Answer (score 4):

@user1774357 I know this is old but I may help someone else.

I wrote this solution in ruby.

The image explains https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXVsY.jpg

1. Get the south west, and north east coordiate.
2. Then you will have to create the coordinates for a grid. For ruby I used the `GeoPoint` gem. For a point I can say give me the coordinates 1km west of this point `GeoPoint.new(point_1.destination_point(0, 1.0).to_dms)`
3. Once you have the list of coordinates (from the grid) send them all one by one to Google Places to generate a list. In the image there's 20 points so I had to send 20 requests which took about 1 minute.
4. Merge the list and make sure they're unique.

Answer (score 3):

[**Contact Google sales**](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/contact.html) to get a business license with [**higher usage limits**](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps-compare.html).... or are you trying to scrape results?

Comment: Yes,I want to collect the results of Japan.  Because I want to use the mobile app development. Is it impossible to collect all of the data?  I'm looking for a way close to three weeks. I want you can or can not answer soon

Comment: It is not possible to get access to more than 60 results with a business license, this is a service restriction.

Comment: AFAIK, with a business license you negotiate your own terms. Several of my clients use business licenses and quotas have been adjusted to their needs.

Comment: Thank you for reply Chris Green.  I was saved because it has been found that can not.

Comment: Thank you for reply Marcelo. To obtain a business license, I do I want suggestions for search results for Google?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking in your last comment but anyway, you might need to re-think your strategy. If you want all post offices in Japan then Google Places is not the way to go, unless you're prepared to buy their entire database. :-)

Comment: I'm sorry, I can not understand much English. However, I can understand that you must change the strategy. Thank you for letting me know. I'll try to think of another way.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but thought I'd point out [Radar Search to get up to 200 places](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-radar-search</s). The response just returns the place id, which you can then use to get the details.

Radar Search is deprecated as of June 30, 2017. This feature is turned down as of June 30, 2018.

Comment: Radar Search should be exactly what I needed. Except for this I must also inform a `keyword`, `name` or `type` in the search.
So watch out for this [not so small] caveat.

Comment: Is there any alternative to radar search which can return more than 60 results.

Comment: @RaviChaudhary There does not appear to be, unfortunately.